# How to record internal audio?

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

I'm currently developing a mobile game that can be recorded while playing. And microphone is need during the game.

So I want to record the game background music, the game sound effects ,and 
 human voice from microphone.

I can record all the sounds through microphone now. But I can not hear the background music and sound effects clearly after the record is finished.

So，I want to know If I can record all the game sounds internally. I googled a lot And I found AudioRecord can do that by set the audio source to REMOTE_SUBMIX. But this is not allowed by non-system app in android.

So, is there any way to record internal audio in Android?

Comment: you developed game in android studio or any other tool?

Comment: @MuhammadHassaan in android studio